# How to show popup on button click in MVC3 using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show popup box on simple HTML button click using jQuery in MVC3.  What would be a sample of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To handle button click events and show a `div` on the click you can do:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#yourDialog").show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yGtwT/

You could also use a `jQuery Dialog` to show a "popup".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourDialog").dialog();
}); 

$("#button").click(function() {
   $("#yourDialog").dialog('open');
});​
```

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Use something jquery library that contains modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I display a pop up box that selects various tag values, first the html:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="tagDialogBox" title="Add Tags">
    @* other html here *@
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery, note that you need to add *.parent().appendTo($("formname"))* in order to allow the dialog fields to be submitted as part of the form:

```
function showTagDialogBox() {
    $('#tagDialogBox').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        title: "Select Tags",
        modal: true,
        height: 530,
        width: 800,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely simple.

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('dialogbox').dialog();"/>
```

Also, examples on the jquery ui page.  This one is very simple (though it also includes animation, you can pull that out as an example)

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated